# What does "across" mean in poker?

Tags: terminology

I've been watching some episodes of Poker After Dark and heard the players use the term "across" in a sentence such as "I had 4 across". (or "a cross" perhaps?)

What does it mean? I'm thinking it means they have that many outs in the deck but I am not sure.

Edit: I've been continuing to watch the episodes in hopes of finding someone saying it in a sentence and finally come across it in a video that I can share with. It is said by Huck and Doyle at 11:58 in [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_MN917l70Og)

Comment: is it a reference to winning cards that only you can win with - for example 4H might win for you but also wins for him?

Comment: It doesn't look like it. I am not even sure what it is in reference to.

Comment: Link to video is broken... :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In "n across," n refers to the number of pips on one side of the card for cards that have more than one column of pips. So, the 4 and 5 would be "2 across" cards; the 6, 7 and 8 would be "3 across" and the 9 and 10 would be "4 across."

[image: 9 is 4-across, 6 is 3-across, 4 is 2-across]

In the clip you linked in your edit (which was very helpful for reminding me of the answer, thanks!) they were both excited because there was a fraction of a second where they realized the river was a 4-across card but didn't know which, and it mattered. The 10 would seal it for Doyle, while the 9 would make Dwan's straight.